# La consulta SHOW TABLES devuelve una lista vacía

Tags: python, base-de-datos

Estoy usando el módulo **mysql.connector** en una clase de Python. Dentro de la clase tengo los métodos siguientes:

```
def create_connection(self):
    connection = dbc.connect(
        host = self.host, 
        user = self.user, 
        password = self.password
    )
    self.connection = connection

def create_cursor(self):
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

Estos métodos se ejecutan correctamente, y crean la conexión y el cursor, eso ya lo he comprobado. También tengo el siguiente método:

```
def show_databases(self):
    self.cursor.execute("show databases")
    bases = [base[0] for base in self.cursor.fetchall()]
    return bases
```

Este funciona correctamente también. Selecciono una base de datos de mi ordenador con el siguiente método:

```
def select_database(self, database):
    self.database = database
    self.cursor.execute(f"create database if not exists {self.database}")
    self.cursor.execute(f"use {self.database}")
    self.connection.commit()
    print (self.connection.database)
```

Esto también funciona correctamente. Y ahora viene el problema. Intento recuperar la lista de las tablas, así:

```
def get_tables(self):
    self.cursor.execute(f"show tables")
    tables = [table[0] for table in self.cursor.fetchall()]
    return tables
```

Me he asegurado de que la base de datos que estoy usando tiene tablas. Sin embargo lo que obtengo es una lista vacía, como si no hubiera tablas. Cual es el problema? Por qué no obtengo la lista de las tablas? He probado a preguntarle a ChatGPT, pero no da con la solución, y en internet no he encontrado tampoco una solución al problema.

Answer (score -1):

Tal vez Python tenga problemas con el `SHOW TABLES;`

Prueba con un `SELECT` más convencional que además te puede proporcionar mucha más información:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='nombre_de_tu_base_de_datos';
```

El equivalente para bases de datos sería:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME
  FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

Comment: Me temo que no has entendido la pregunta. SHOW DATABASES me funciona perfectamente. El problema lo tengo con SHOW TABLES. Es decir, selecciono una base de datos, esto me funciona perfectamente. Luego intento recuperar una lista de las tablas que tiene esa base de datos, y sólo obtengo una lista vacía. Es decir, la consulta show tales no está funcionando. ¿Hay alguna solución para eso? Gracias.

Comment: Pues sí, todos los metadatos del servidor están en la base de datos `information_schema`, donde tienes tanto el `SHOW TABLES` como el `SHOW DATABASES`. Te amplío la respuesta para el caso particular de las tablas.